# Inserting html code after creating div problem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello i am trying to dynamically create divs, at a button click, and append a span element to it. When i click the button a function is called and a div is created but i can't display the contents of the span element.
I basically have a container div and want to create divs inside that container, with the contents of the span element present, through javascript.

```
function createDiv ()
{
    
  var boxEle = document.createElement('div');
  var container = document.querySelector('.container'); 

  
  boxEle.setAttribute('id','box_id'+ dynamicid());
  //console.log(boxEle.id);
  boxEle.style.width = "40%";
  boxEle.style.height = "500px";
  boxEle.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; 
  boxEle.style.margin = "20px";
  boxEle.style.boxsizing = "border-box";

  boxEle.innerHTML = '<span class="list-names"></span>';

  container.appendChild(boxEle);
}
```

This span will show a list of names that were fetched from a database. The idea was to create how many divs i wanted with the list present in every created div.

If i change the span element and insert some random text it works fine. I also tried to create a php file with just the span element there and used jquery load to insert it into my div but it only works on the first div, if i create more than one then nothing shows on the rest.
After looking on here i tried to do everything with jquery but the problem was the same.

```
$(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $('#creatediv_id').click(function(){
      $('#container_id').append('<div id="first'+count+'"><span class="list-names"></span></div>');
      count++;
    });
  });
```

Don't really know what else i should try or if it is doomed.

Comment: First things first, why are you mixing vanilla Javascript and jQuery in your code? Can't you just pick one of them?

Comment: Its just vanilla, i just tried jquery to see if it would work

Comment: I am sorry for closing your other question, closed it mostly to prevent hasty low quality answers. Your problem there is not PDO related. You need to collect your data in a single array an a loop. Where each row represents a complete row in the database, with pairs column name => value. Then prepare the query once, and run execute an a loop

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code works just fine, did you check DOM after click, because elements are there, but your span hasn't got any text, so there is nothing on the screen, here is example with jQuery way:

```js
$(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $('#creatediv_id').click(function(){
      $('#container_id').append('<div id="first'+count+'"><span class="list-names">test</span></div>');
      count++;
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="creatediv_id">Create Div</button>
<div id="container_id"></div>
```

Comment: If i add it directly on the page it shows the content, but if i try to do it this way nothing shows.

Comment: Which way ? Based on the code you provide right now, there is no problem. If you face problem with fetching some data from the database, you should provide more info.

Comment: I fetch the data in php and send it to a javascript file. The javascript file receives the data and inserts it like this:          const content = document.querySelector(".list-names");

        
        if (content) {

            content.innerHTML = answ['dados'];
        }; With ans being the data from the php file